# Rails page life cycle, good write ups/tutorials on this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to read about, in detail, a rails page life cycle, along with the initial page request that loads the website.

I have no idea what's going on here :)

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to tell -- a request gets routed to a Controller, and the Controller responds by either rendering a page or redirecting the request to another page.

Then there's the Rack middleware stack. You can see the stack by running `rake middleware`. Every request works its way down the chain before hitting the Controller, and then goes back up the way it came. A lot of framework stuff is actually running on top the application as middleware.

[Tekpub](http://tekpub.com) has a [pretty good screencast on Rack middleware](http://tekpub.com/view/rack/1) for free. (You have to create a free account first -- OpenID is supported)

O'Reilly has a pretty good introduction chapter to Rails [available here](http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html).